# I can´t view the events in the full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

im trying to show the events in the fullcalendar but I can´t, in the database I have a datetime in this format MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss as you can see fullcalendar recommended to use  ISO8601 for a dates, the when I make a query for get the events I convert the date in ISO8601 with the CONVERT sentence, the server response is fine but I can´t still see the events

this my code on the server side for get the events:

```
//para la agenda
    public function getCitas(){


        $citas =  $this->db->select('CONVERT(VARCHAR, Citas.fecha_hora, 126) AS start, cita_id AS cita_id, 
                                    Citas.CLAVE_PAC, CONVERT(VARCHAR, Citas.fecha_hora, 126) AS fecha_hora, Paciente.Nombre as title, 
                                    Paciente.CentroSal_de_Procedencia, Paciente.Telefonos,
                                    Paciente.Municipio, sub_especialidades.nombre_sub_esp, citas.sub_esp_id, usuario.nombre as agendado_por')
                                   ->from('citas')
                                   ->join('sub_especialidades', 'sub_especialidades.sub_esp_id=citas.sub_esp_id')
                                   ->join('Paciente', 'Paciente.CLAVE_PAC=Citas.CLAVE_PAC')
                                   ->join('usuario', 'usuario.id_usuario=citas.agendo')
                                   ->where('citas.cita_status', 1)
                                   ->where('sub_especialidades.id_especialidad', $_POST['agendaId'])
                                   ->get('')
                                   ->result();





         echo json_encode($citas);

    }
```

The event source:

```
 {
        url: 'index.php/agenda/getCitas',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            agendaId: '<?php echo $agendaId; ?>',

        },
        error: function() {
            alert('no se pudieron obtener las citas');
        }
    }
```

The response looks fine, what am I doing wrong?
[Response img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/envWV.png)